# SNMP response mangled by PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, snmp

Consider the following PowerShell code:

```
$SNMP = New-Object -COMObject OLEPrn.OLESNMP
$SNMP.Open("10.178.230.105", "public", 2, 3000)
$MACAddress = $SNMP.Get(".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.1")
$SNMP.Close()
```

At this point, `$MACAddress` is supposed to contain a six-byte string, which when decoded to hex, should be the MAC Address of the printer. This is a Xerox printer, and the first two bytes are supposed to be `0x9C 0x93`. However,

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 6; $i++) {
    "{0}: {1:X2}" -f $MACAddress[$i],[BYTE]$MACAddress[$i]
}
```

throws an error for the first two bytes:

```
Cannot convert value "œ" to type "System.Byte". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte."
At Z:\Scripts\Powershell\SNMPscratch.ps1:10 char:4
+    "{0}: {1:X2}" -f $MACAddress[$i],[BYTE]$MACAddress[$i]
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastIConvertible

Cannot convert value "“" to type "System.Byte". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte."
At Z:\Scripts\Powershell\SNMPscratch.ps1:10 char:4
+    "{0}: {1:X2}" -f $MACAddress[$i],[BYTE]$MACAddress[$i]
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastIConvertible

N: 4E
s: 73
-: 2D
|: 7C
```

(The last four bytes are correctly converted.)

If I cast to an `[int]` instead, and make the field for the hex value four characters instead:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 6; $i++) {
    "{0}: {1:X4}" -f $MACAddress[$i],[int]$MACAddress[$i]
}
```

I get no error, but...

```
œ: 0153
“: 201C
N: 004E
s: 0073
-: 002D
|: 007C
```

... where the first two "bytes" are *not* `0x9C 0x93`, the way they're supposed to be.

What's going wrong, where, and how do I fix it or work around it?

***Supplemental information:***

I thought that perhaps the encoding was the problem, and tried

```
[byte[]]$MACAddress = ([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII).GetBytes($SNMP.Get(".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.1"))
```

which avoided throwing the error, but generated

```
63: 003F
63: 003F
78: 004E
115: 0073
45: 002D
124: 007C
```

which is *also* wrong - but this makes it look like the problem *may* be in `$SNMP.Get()`, rather than in anything I'm doing. If so, is there any alternative, short of using a third-party library, which our Information Security people will *not* approve?

Comment: Can you try this? https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SNMP/1.0.0.1/Content/SNMP.psm1 It uses my open source SharpSnmpLibrary which should be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: @LexLi - With that module - which is actually where I started before I was told that using the DLL for the 'production' code would not be approved - I was having the same problem; the string I was getting was the same as when I did the `[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII...` hack - i.e., `0x9C 0x93` was coming out `0x3F 0x3F`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, "[System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes()".  Although if the mac address begins with a 0, .Get() returns an empty string.  There's always an old version of the Net-SNMP snmpwalk windows binary.

```
# snmpmac.ps1

param($PrinterAddress)

$oid = '.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.1' # mac address

$SNMP = New-Object -ComObject olePrn.OleSNMP

foreach($printer in $PrinterAddress) {
  $SNMP.Open($Printer, "public", 2, 3000)

  $string = $SNMP.Get($oid)

  $MacAddress = ([System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes($string) |
    % tostring X2) -join '-'
  [pscustomobject]@{Name = $Printer; MacAddress = $MacAddress}
  $SNMP.Close()
}
```

```
.\snmpmac a-cp2,a-mfp1,a-mfp2,a-mfp3,a-mfp4

Name        MacAddress
----        ----------
a-cp2
a-mfp1      58-38-79-23-AE-54
a-mfp2      58-38-79-23-AD-E8
a-mfp3      58-38-79-23-AE-70
a-mfp4      58-38-79-23-B0-B0
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a few incorrect statements.

First, Xerox reserves `9C:93:4E`, so checking the first two bytes `9C:93` is not enough. [Reference](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf)

Second, `3F:3F:4E` is valid, and is locally administered MAC address, assigned to a device by an administrator. Such addresses do not contain OUIs for vendor recognition.

Guess this device probably has multiple NICs, so you should make a WALK operation to check all NICs, and don't blindly go to the very first in the table.

Comment: The MAC that's reported by the device, for the purposes of setting DHCP reservations, is `9C:93:4E:73:2D:7C`, as seen on the configuration page that it prints out, and the internal web server when the configuration is queried. I have been using that for comparison because it's known; we want to be able to retrieve the data from other printers for the purposes of compiling certain information relevant to troubleshooting efforts, because our call center is not requesting proper information from the users. [more]...

Comment: ...[more] There is only one ethernet interface in the device, and if I could get past the encoding/translation issue, I'm certain that I would be getting the MAC above - but I need to be able to _prove_ that I'm getting the right information, before I can start interrogating other printers on our network. I'm not doing this to use the information to try to figure out what I've got; I'm trying to get accurate information between our inventory control and our configuration, so that when we troubleshoot, we'll _have_ the info instead of wasting time trying to contact the user to get it.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I can only say you are out of luck right now. Time to Xerox support for explanation on this weird behavior (why a `3F:3F:4E` address is returned), and SNMP protocol and the tooling you use are no longer the cause.

Comment: It's not the printer; it's PowerShell. And in your module, it's because you're calling the ToString() method when you're formatting the data into the PSCustomObject - regardless of the encoding, it doesn't seem to handle the bytes with values above `0x7F` in a usable way.

Comment: `OCTET STRING` is raw bytes. **My code does not call ToString() in any case when handling SNMP `OCTET STRING`**. I don't claim anything on `OLEPrn.OLESNMP` as that's not something I know. If the PowerShell module calls `ToString`, that's the bug of itself.

Comment: The PowerShell code that accompanies your DLL most certainly does. Are you saying that someone else wrote the PowerShell code?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin someone else created the module and published it. Out of my control.

Comment: OK, my apologies for any implied accusation. I'll try to hack on the OLE stuff a bit more, as that's what I'm going to have to use for the job - and on your DLL so I can use something nicer at home. :)